# Find a convergent function in metric space

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $C[−1, 1]$ be the space of continuous functions equipped with the metric $p(f,g) = \max\{|f(x)−g(x)| \mid x \in [−1, 1]\}$.

Then the sequence of functions $(f_n):[−1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$f_n(x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right).$$
I have already proved that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy.

Then how to  find a function $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ to which $(f_n)$ converges in $C([-1, 1], p)$?

Comment: sorry, corrected. (fn）converges to f

Comment: just corrected, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should determine whether there is a pointwise limit first. If not, there will a fortiori not be a uniform limit. But here there is one. By continuity of $\cos $ at $0$, the pointwise limit is constant equal to $\cos(0)=1$.

For uniform convergence, use the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to show that for every $x$
$$
\Big|\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\cos(0)\Big|=\big|\sin\left(c_{x,n}\right)\Big|\Big| \frac{x}{n}-0\Big|
$$
for some $c_{x,n}$ between $0$ and $x/n$. Can you conclude?

**Note:** you do not need to prove that the sequence is Cauchy. Finding the pointwise limit and proving uniform convergence is a procedure which applies to most exercises of this type.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the pointwise limit. For $|x| \le 1$, which is in your domain, you have $x/n \to 0$ as $n$ grows to infinity. Hence, $cos(x/n) \to 1$ as $n$ grows, for any $x$ in your domain. This is the good candidate for your limit, and in fact it is the limit itself.

Comment: cool, thanks！ I got it